# Unable to return the correct result of the function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am just a beginner at learning code with no prior knowledge at all.

I wrote a simple code below to apply my knowledge of defining functions and a for loop to work. This code will supposedly allow the user to obtain any numeral to a power based on their input. However, as you will observe below, I will always get a result of 0.

I am honestly not sure where I went wrong and have been told that my code is not the most readable. As such, I will like to seek your help in enlightening me what is wrong with it and how to make it better.

Thank you very much guys!

```
def to_power(base, power):
    result = 1
    for base in range(power):
        result = result * base
    return int(result)


print(to_power(int(input("Enter Base Number: ")), int(input("Enter Power: "))))
```

> Enter Base Number: 4
>   Enter Power: 4
>   0
>   Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. This is a working version of your code.

Problem with your code:

- `range(power)` will generate values starting from `0` up to `power-1`. You were using `base` to iterate over these values and since you were using `result = result * base`, you were multiplying by 0 which is why you are getting 0

Solution:

- You need to just iterate a loop for `power` number of times and keep multiplying `base` for that many (`power`) number of times. Since the index of the loop is unused here, I used `_` in `for _ in range(power):`

---

```
def to_power(base, power): 
    result = 1 
    for _ in range(power): 
        result = result * base 
    return int(result)

print(to_power(int(input("Enter Base Number: ")), int(input("Enter Power: "))))

# Enter Base Number: 4
# Enter Power: 4
# 256
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I am still unsure about the rationale behind the index of the loop. Kindly correct me if I am wrong, but why is it that `_`, which seems to be undefined, be able to prevent the result from going to 0. Also, isn't the index of the loop the position of any value within a string and list?
Lastly, why is it that my input for `base` be translated to 0 when my input != 0?

Comment: I apologies for my many questions as I am very new and will really like to understand the logic behind the codes and functions. I am sincerely appreciative of the help given by you guys

Comment: @ExiligeZs: The `range(power):` will result in a generator which has a length equal to power (4 in this case). You could also use `for i in range(power): ` but then you are not using the index `i` in your for loop. So basically `i` is just a dummy index whose main purpose is to create a for loop 4 times. In such cases, you can use `_` just to avoid unused variables in your code. The result will not go to zero because as I said, you are not using the index generated by the for loop anywhere. You are just using the loop to run your multiplier `result = result * base ` 4 times

Comment: @ExiligeZs: You can also read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122109/how-do-you-make-a-for-loop-when-you-dont-need-index-in-python) for more on `_`

Comment: I see, thank you very much for the input! This was not taught in the online tutorial I was learning from and now I understand how I can include dummy indexes to make the loop run 'n' number of times

Comment: @ExiligeZs and marking this post as an accepted answer helps the community, so please take a few seconds to upvote and mark :)

Comment: Done and really appreciate the help guys

Answer (score 0):

looks like this is what you want:

```
def to_power(base, power):
   result = 1
   for i in range(power):
     result = result * base
return int(result)
```

Example:

```
to_power(4,4)
Out[5]: 256
```